# How to configure MongoDB in java without Spring to access a common connection pool? How to make a common connection to DB with singleton pattern?

Tags: java, mongodb, database-connection

I have a scenario where I need to configure the Mongo DB in Java Application. I don't use Spring, but I need to make the connection to DB as common so that whenever there is a transaction that is going to happen, it must create a connection automatically and it must close the connection when the transaction is done.

**EDIT**:

How to make the connection common instead of creating the instance each time when the transactions are done?

Comment: I think the driver does that by default. Have you checked the documentation of mongoclient?

Comment: @ernest_k I tried to but didn't find any proper resource.

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html. The first sentence already says `A MongoDB client with internal connection pooling`

Comment: @ernest_k So it means that, whenever the object is initialized, then the internal connection pooling will be taken care by the driver itself?

Comment: As I understand it, yes. And when you make database calls, you can see in the logs that the driver opens many connections. But I don't know whether what you want is to customize that behavior or the pool size.

Comment: I am new to Mongo DB. So, I am learning to integrate the Mongo DB with Java as like how an enterprise application will make the connection. So, when there is a high load, this must handle the connection pooling.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of transactions working with Java code (and without Spring):
Article: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/java-and-mongodb-40-support-for-multidocument-acid-transactions
GitHub: https://github.com/MaBeuLux88/mongodb-4.0-demos